# How do you create a number input without the increment/decrement buttons?

Tags: css, html

How can I have an input of type number without the little increment and decrement arrows?

```
<input type="number">
```

[image: number input]

not the box above just a normal plain input!
I realise I could use a text input with a regex, but is there a way using the number type?

Comment: I did search and it didn't come up but thanks anyway pal!

Comment: But... Why don't use the input text element?